# Orchard custom settings usage and parts

Tags: settings, orchardcms

Scenario

One part for edit settings, one different part for consuming settings

I'm following this help:
http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Adding-custom-settings

For settings part no problem.

For consuming I would to return a custom shape instead of null if settings are not set.
This will be a simple view with a link inviting user to go to settings and set them properly before continue.
NOTE: the consuming part is not a display but on editor... if this matters.

```
// Prevent share bar from showing if account is not set
if (shareSettings == null || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(shareSettings.AddThisAccount)) {
    return null;
}
```

Now I'm stuck on what to write there instead of return null.
I have tried to do something like that but a null reference is logged.

```
return ContentShape("Parts_MyPart_SettingsMessage",
       () => shapeHelper.Parts_MyPart_SettingsMessage());
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you created the view? What have you called it? Where is it stored?

Answer (score 1):

I have tried this:

```
 return ContentShape("Parts_MyPart_SettingsMessage", () =>    
    shapeHelper.EditorTemplate(TemplateName: "Parts/MyPart.SettingsMessage"));
```

And seems it works... for now. I'm further investigating why part is not olways loaded but just sometimes...